# display icons instead of classes names when displaying records to users in mvc

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, font-awesome

am using jquery dataTable in mvc to display records. now there is one column Icon in my category table which contains names of font awsome icon classes like "fa fa-plus". now what i want is to [display icons instead of these classes names when displaying records to users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hs7L.jpg)

**this is my jquery datTable code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  dataTable = $("#categoryTable").DataTable({

    "ajax": {
      "url": "/Category/GetData",
      "type": "Get",
      "datatype": "json"
    },
    "columns": [

      {
        "data": "CategoryName"
      },
      {
        "data": "Description"
      },
      {
        "data": "Icon"
      },
        "orderable": false,
        "searchable": false,
        "width": "150px"
      }
    ],
    "language": {
      "emptyTable": "No Data Found Plese Click <b>Add Category</b> Button"
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check updated script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  dataTable = $("#categoryTable").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": "/Category/GetData",
      "type": "Get",
      "datatype": "json"
    },
    "columns": [
      {
        "data": "CategoryName"
      },
      {
        "data": "Description"
      },
      {
        "data": "Icon",
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            return '<i class="' + data + '"></i>';
        }
      },
        "orderable": false,
        "searchable": false,
        "width": "150px"
      }
    ],
    "language": {
      "emptyTable": "No Data Found Plese Click <b>Add Category</b> Button"
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: what i want is <i class="should be coming from database"></i>

Comment: Please share a full example JS, JSON and HTML

Comment: display page got blank, but I think we are going to achieve something with this change, let me try i will inform u if get it Thanks @wael Abbas

Comment: It worked Bro! Thank u so Much @Wael Abbas. and by the way your code was perfect

Comment: Welcome @Abbas Khan :)